# Configure GCS as Parse Server storage

Tags: parse-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to use GCS as a storage for my files in Parse Server. I followed the [tutorial](http://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#configuring-gcsadapter), installing the `parse-server-gcs-adapter` and setting the environment variables in my `.bashrc`:

> export PARSE_SERVER_FILES_ADAPTER=parse-server-gcs-adapter
>
> export GCP_PROJECT_ID=my-project-id
>
> export GCP_KEYFILE_PATH=path-to-keyfile.json
>
> export GCS_BUCKET=my-bucket-name
>
> export GCS_DIRECT_ACCESS=true

I can upload files in my Parse Dashboard, and they are correctly saved in the class, but the files cannot be seen in the bucket browser.

Some sources such as [this one](https://medium.com/google-cloud/deploying-parse-server-to-google-app-engine-6bc0b7451d50) talk about a config file, but I cannot find info about this file anywhere.

I want to know if there is any means to debug what is happening, or if there is anything obvious that I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I could get the solution for the issue.

The first thing (debug what was happening) was to take a look (*tail -f*) at the log file, located at */opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/logs/parse.log*. There, I could see nothing was happening, thus confirming my suspicion about not changing the right file. Then, I located the config file that I was looking for to be */opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/server.js*, being able to configure it as [written in the Parse docs](http://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#passing-as-options-1).

As I had another problem with the GCS Adapter, I also found an issue with Bitnami machines, that was identical to [this answer to an issue in Github](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/3438#issuecomment-276433306). Now it's all working.